# Scroll even if the seekbar is touched

Tags: android, scrollview, seekbar, motionevent

I am using a seekbar in a linearlayout in a ScroolView in a NavigationDrawer

> NavigationDrawer > ScrollView > LinearLayout > SeekBar + other stuff

When I touch the seekbar I am unable to scroll up and down and I'd like to.

Here my function which allow me to slide the seekbar instead of slide the navigation drawer

```
private View onCritereView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_critere, container, false);
    LinearLayout mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) mView.findViewById(R.id.critere_linearlayout);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < mTitles.length; i++) {
        View mViewElement = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_critere, null);
        ((TextView) mViewElement.findViewById(R.id.critere_title)).setText(mTitles[i]);
        SeekBar mSeekBar = (SeekBar) mViewElement.findViewById(R.id.critere_qualifier);
        mSeekBar.setOnTouchListener(new ListView.OnTouchListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
            {
                int action = event.getAction();
                switch (action)
                {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        // Disallow Drawer to intercept touch events.
                        v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        // Allow Drawer to intercept touch events.
                        v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                        break;
                }

                // Handle seekbar touch events.
                v.onTouchEvent(event);
                return true;
            }
        });
        mLinearLayout.addView(mViewElement);
    }
    return mView;
}
```

Now what I need is:

> If you touch the seekbar and if you slide hozizontaly use seekbar.
>
> else if you touch the seekbar and if you slide verticaly use scrollview

How can I do that ?

Thanks in advance :)